# Multiplication table?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I need to Write 2 web pages with the following attributes:

- Form (decide if this should be html or jsp file).
  Form contains an HTML form with two fields:a text input (called "size") and a button.

When the button is clicked, another page appears..

- Table (decide if this is HTML or JSP)
  Table shows the multipications table up to the "size" in the previous page.

Example:
If 3 was clicked, then the output will be:

```
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

Also, add a button to Table so that pressing this button will make the table disappear.

Here is my form code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>multiplication table</h1>
    <form action="form_action.jsp" method="get">
        Size: <input type="size" name="size" size="35" /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <p>Click on the submit button, and the input will be sent to a page
        on the server called "form_action.jsp".</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and my page generating multipications table

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<head>
<title>Calculation from a form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Calculation</div>
    <table border="Calculation">
        <%
            String temp = request.getParameter("number");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            String table = "<table border='1' id='mytable'>";
            for (int row = 1; row < 11; row++) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <%
                for (int column = 1; column < 11; column++) {
            %>
            <td><tt><%=row * column%></tt></td>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me to begin this?

Comment: this is my first page:<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>multiplication table</h1>
        <form action="form_action.jsp" method="get">
            Size: <input type="size" name="size" size="35" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <p>Click on the submit button, and the input will be sent to a page on the server called "form_action.jsp".</p>

    </body>
</html>

Comment: second one:<head><title>Calculation from a form</title></head>
<body>

    <div>Calculation</div>

    <table border="Calculation">

        <% String temp = request.getParameter("number");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            String table = "<table border='1' id='mytable'>";
            for (int row = 1; row < 11; row++) {%>
        <tr>
            <% for (int column = 1; column < 11; column++) {%> <td><tt><%= row * column%></tt></td>
            <% }%>
</tr>
<% }%>
</table>
</script>

Comment: I moved code from your comments to question so you can remove them

Answer (score 0):

In your first page you have input named size `<input type="size" name="size" size="35" />` but in `form_action.jsp` you are trying to get value from `number`

```
String temp = request.getParameter("number");
```

change it to `size`

```
String temp = request.getParameter("size");
```

You are parsing this value to `int x` but then you never use it in your `for`s. Correct that and it will be fine.

Comment: changed it and still not working please help me a bit more :)

Comment: How exactly is it "now working"? What you expect and what you actually see?

Comment: i see the first page grate but when i press a number it give me the whole multipications table and not just the nuber iv printed in the first page

Comment: You probably didn't update `for` loops to use `x` as max value. Change them to something like `for (int row = 1; row <= x; row++)`

Comment: god bless u pshemo lol, now finally need a button to Table so that pressing this button will make the table disappear.

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to help resolve code problems, not to produce code for others. Show me problem with code, and I will try to help but don't expect people will do your homework for you

Comment: <button type="button" onClick="documentElementById"('x');">disappear</button>

Comment: try this way: `<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('x').style.display ='none';"> disappear </button>` and don't forget to add id attribute to table tag `<table border="Calculation" id="x">`

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want:form_action.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>multiplication table</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <%
            int size = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("size"));
            for (int row = 1; row <= size; row++) {
            %>
            <tr>
            <%
                for (int column = 1; column <= size; column++) {
                    %>
                    <td><%=row*column %></td>
                    <%
                }
            %>
            </tr>
            <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: doest generate a multiplication table

Comment: ok now i need this:Table shows the multipications table up to the "size" in the previous page.
Example:
If 3 was clicked, then the output will be:

1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9